# ExtGWT StoreFilterField input doesn't react

Tags: java, extjs, gxt

I'm trying to build grid with build in column filtering (using sencha gxt), here is my code:

```
public Grid<Stock> createGrid() {


    // Columns definition
    ColumnConfig<Stock, String> nameCol     = new ColumnConfig<Stock, String>(props.name(),     100,    "Company");

    // Column model definition and creation
    List<ColumnConfig<Stock, ?>> cl = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Stock, ?>>();
    cl.add(nameCol);
    ColumnModel<Stock> cm = new ColumnModel<Stock>(cl);

    // Data populating
    ListStore<Stock> store = new ListStore<Stock>(props.key());
    store.addAll(TestData.getStocks());


    // Grid creation with data
    final Grid<Stock> grid = new Grid<Stock>(store, cm);
    grid.getView().setAutoExpandColumn(nameCol);
    grid.setBorders(false);
    grid.getView().setStripeRows(true);
    grid.getView().setColumnLines(true);


    // Filters definition
    StoreFilterField<Stock> filter = new StoreFilterField<Stock>() {

        @Override
        protected boolean doSelect(Store<Stock> store, Stock parent, Stock item, String filter) {

           // Window.alert(String.valueOf("a"));

           String name = item.getName();
            name = name.toLowerCase();
            if (name.startsWith(filter.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    filter.bind(store);

    cm.addHeaderGroup(0, 0, new HeaderGroupConfig(filter, 1, 1));
    filter.focus();
    return grid;
}
```

My problem is: after I run this code, I cannot write anything to filter input, I'm using test data and classes (Stock.java and StockProperties.java) from this example: http://sencha.com/examples-dev/#ExamplePlace:filtergrid
I try to put allert in doSelect method to check if this function was called, but it wasn't.
Any idea will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem according to this paper  http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/ … but I replace `disableTextSelection(false)` with `setAllowTextSelection(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make your code work. I observed that there were compiler errors in the code for StoreFilterField class. Here is the code that filters the grid based on the values in the first column, that is, name field in the Stock model.

```
StoreFilterField<Stock> filter1 = new StoreFilterField<Stock>() {

@Override
protected boolean doSelect(Store<Stock> store, Stock parent, Stock record, String property, String filter) {
    String name = record.get("name");
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    if (name.startsWith(filter.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
};

filter1.bind(store);
```

Btw, I tested this with GXT 2.2.5 and GWT 2.4.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Thanks for your time, I solve this problem according to this paper http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-91956.html?s=8d0140f4c37e7d598bd3f99f6ad66832 but I repleace disableTextSelection(false) with setAllowTextSelection(true);